# PyQuery: extract id from html?

Tags: python, html, attr, pyquery

I try to get all the "id" from an html file with PyQuery, but is bringing troubles...I try this:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

file = open('index.html', 'r').read
jQuery = PyQuery(html)

jQuery.attr('id')
```

But shows nothing...

Help me please.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not sure if your example code is what you're using but you're missing a few different things there, like calling `read()` instead of making `file` the `read` method, and then you're never using it. You're also passing in `html` when you never assigned anything to it.

But here's something I wrote that seems to find all elements with an `id`, I tried following your names as best as I could, but I didn't want to reuse `file` since that's a reserved word as far as I know:

```
from pyquery import PyQuery

html = open('temp.html').read()

jquery = PyQuery(html)
ids = jquery.find('[id]')

print ids
>>>[<link#screen-switcher-stylesheet>, <div#search>, <input#term.input-text>, <input#submit.input-button>]
```

Comment: thanks TankorSmash, I did not explain very well. I need the script take de name of id's in html. For example: <div id="hello">content</div>, the script have to give me "hello"

Comment: @Benyi No problem at all! If the solution works for you, please feel free to click the checkmark near my answer to mark this question as solved.